# Is docker checkpoint supported for windows containers, or does it rely on CRIU?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-container

The goal is to make container create or start faster from a "clean" state for an image whose build contains a long-running application installation. I thought two options would be to `docker export` immediately following the container creation (not supported on windows) or `docker checkpoint` immediately following the container creation.

Trying to checkpoint a windows container,

```
docker checkpoint create my_container my_container_checkpoint
```

the command seems to hang and event log shows:

```
 Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
 ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
 3595658 Feb 05 11:31  Information docker                          2 debug: Calling GET /_ping
 3595659 Feb 05 11:31  Information docker                          2 debug: Calling GET /v1.35/containers/my_container/export
 3595666 Feb 05 11:33  Information docker                          2 debug: Calling POST /v1.35/containers/my_container/checkpoints
 3595667 Feb 05 11:33  Information docker                          2 debug: form data: {"CheckpointDir":"","CheckpointID":"my_container_checkpoint","Exit":true}
 3595665 Feb 05 11:33  Information docker                          2 debug: Calling GET /_ping
```

Version info:

```
Version 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)
Channel: stable
9c692cd
```

Comment: I'm having looking at trying to get the same working my understanding is that dokcer server needs to support CRIU Checkpoint/Restore In Userspace. From errors it looks like at present this is not support in moby linux that windosw is using.